# Three.js "Context Lost" and "Multiple instances being imported"?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, three.js

I'm trying to create a 3D editor, where the user can edit a 3D scene, and then hit a "play" button and see the result. To render the result, I'm using an `iframe`. Here is my `HTML` code:

```html
<iframe id="testing_frame" class="ui"></iframe>
```

The class `ui` is just `position: absolute; top: 0;`. I don't want to have a `URL` or `FILE` as the `src` to this `iframe`, instead I want to write directly to it. Here is how I do it:

```js
generatedCode += `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r134/three.min.js"><\/script>
    </head>

    <body style="margin: 0;">
        <script async>"use strict"
            function init(){
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();
                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0xff0000
                }));
                scene.add(mesh);
                camera.position.z = -5;
                camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                function animate() {
                    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                }
                animate();
            }

            window.onload = init;
        <\/script>
    </body>

    </html>`;
```

That code is stored in the variable `generatedCode`, which is what I will write to the `iframe`, here:

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("testing_frame");
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    
iframeDocument.open();
iframeDocument.write(generatedCode);
iframeDocument.close();
```

This works fine.

***My Problem: I have a `start/stop` button, which runs this code everytime it is clicked. Each time I hit stop, it says `WARNING: Multiple instances of Three.js being imported.`, and if I start and stop the testing iframe around 10 times, it says `THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.`***

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jcjozU2e1mmHShNB-oVZyAWUewisNiD6/view?usp=sharing) I have a video demonstrating my problem. (Don't worry about the things in the console *before* I start doing anything)

Thanks!

## Edit: Here is the start/stop code:

```html
<button id='play_btn' onClick='test_iframe();';>Play</button>
```

This is the button, below is the `test_iframe()` function:

```js
function test_iframe() {
    let code = generateCodeFromProjectData();
    var iframe = document.getElementById("testing_frame");
    var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    
    //Write to iframe
    iframeDocument.open();
    iframeDocument.write(code);
    iframeDocument.close();

    //If they press play, change it to stop and show the iframe.
    if(document.getElementById("play_btn").innerHTML == "Play"){
        document.getElementById("testing_frame").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("play_btn").innerHTML = "Stop";
    } else { //If they press stop, hide the iframe and change it to play.
        document.getElementById("testing_frame").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("play_btn").innerHTML = "Play";
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the `generateCodeFromProjectData()` function, which receives the code:

```js
function generateCodeFromProjectData(){
    generatedCode = "";
    //Opening
    generatedCode += `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r134/three.min.js"><\/script>
    </head>

    <body style="margin: 0;">
        <script async>"use strict"
            function init(){
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();
                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0xff0000
                }));
                scene.add(mesh);
                camera.position.z = -5;
                camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                function animate() {
                    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                }
                animate();
            }

            window.onload = init;
        <\/script>
    </body>

    </html>`;

    return generatedCode;
}
```

## Edit 2: Here's my new code for the `iframe`

```js
generatedCode += `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r134/three.min.js"><\/script>
    </head>

    <body style="margin: 0;">
        <script>
            function init(){
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();
                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0xff0000
                }));
                scene.add(mesh);
                camera.position.z = -5;
                camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                function destroy() {
                    scene = null;
                    camera = null;
                    mesh = null;
                    renderer.dispose()
                }

                return {destroy};

                function animate() {
                    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                }
                animate();
            }
            window.onload = () => {
                var instance = init();
                window.onbeforeunload = () => {
                  instance.destroy();
                }
              }
        <\/script>
    </body>

    </html>`;
```

Now I get no error for `Context Lost`, but the red cube in the center does not show up.

Comment: What I'm trying to say, is that after It says context lost, I don't see the original scene with the sphere and grass. Why is that, and how can I fix this?

Comment: @Ouroborus Okay, give me 5 mins

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you reset the iframe. So I'm guessing that you keep appending the same chunk of code. `.open()` doesn't reset the iframe context (though it does break source view). See the warning for [.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

Comment: @Ouroborus Okay... so what should I do instead of using `document.write()`? Also I edited my post.

Comment: Well, don't use an iframe. But that's going to take a rewrite. A quick fix might be to only do the show/hide portion in response to the button click. The rest (setting variables and setting up the iframe should only be done once, outside of and before that function.

Comment: @Ouroborus Okay.. I think I see what you're saying, but I want the user to be able to change the code in the iframe. Basically they will create a scene in the editor, and when they hit play it will show that scene (right now it just shows a cube), so it is likely that the iframe content will change every time... I don't mind a rewrite though, do you know of a better way to accomplish this (without server side, if possible?)

Comment: Making the iframe navigate to new location or deleting and recreating the iframe would clear its context properly.

Comment: Okay, so if I delete the HTML element and then recreate it every time the play button is hit, would that help? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, that is one way.

Comment: Sorry, could you please show me how I would change `test_iframe()` to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @Ouroborus, sorry im new to iframe

Comment: @Ouroborus, maybe it has something to do with having 2 `THREE.WebGLRenderer`? One in my main project and one in the `iframe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a **memory leak** to me. Anything happened inside `<iframe />` stays in the memory unless it is deallocated manually or the tab(window) is closed. I've experienced exact same problem when using [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) with different frontend libraries; storybook also uses `<iframe />` as an isolated demonstration, but it always needed manual deallocation.

Manual memory deallocation, or `dispose()` function is necessary in Three.JS as well. Here's [an excerpt from the official Three.js document](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=dispose#manual/en/introduction/How-to-dispose-of-objects):

> Why can't three.js dispose objects automatically?
>
> This question was asked many times by the community so it's important to clarify this matter. **Fact is that three.js does not know the lifetime or scope of user-created entities like geometries or materials. This is the responsibility of the application.** For example even if a material is currently not used for rendering, it might be necessary for the next frame. So if the application decides that a certain object can be deleted, it has to notify the engine via calling the respective dispose() method.

It says the dispose is necessary for `Three.Object3D` and says nothing about `WebGLRender`. Interestingly enough, the `dispose()` function is listed as `WebGLRenderer`'s spec.

https://threejs.org/docs/?q=renderer#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer

to sync the dispose action to iframes, use `window.onbeforeunload` event handler or add dispose function to your page move action.

```js
// add this code to your iframe code.
function init () {
  var scene = // ...
  var camera = // ...
  var mesh = // ...
  var renderer = // ...
  /* ... */
  function destroy() {
    scene = null;
    camera = null;
    mesh = null;
    renderer.dispose()
  }
  return {destroy};
}
window.onload = () => {
  var instance = init();
  window.onbeforeunload = () => {
    instance.destroy();
  }
}
```

---

edit: the answer only solves the `context lost` issue. It has no problem in terms of destroying the instance. `Multiple instances being imported` should be regarded as another problem. Anything that's added inside `<iframe/>` is considered in the same scope as its parent. adding `<script src="..." />` inside iframe again and again causes multiple instances being imported. So to solve this issue, code must be provided from its parent.

- `generatedCode` should not include the `<script />`
- code should be provided in the same scope as the iframe controller code, so that it can sync the lifecycle of iframe and three.js renderer.

it's little bit more complex than disposing. here's the working code and working demo at [codepen](https://codepen.io/rabelais88/pen/KKoVOzM)

```html
<script src="your three.js url"></script>
<body>
<div id="root">
</div>

<button id='play_btn' onClick='test_iframe()'>Play</button>
</body>
```

```js
// multiple instances being imported & context lost issue solved
function init(width, height) {
  console.log("init", width, height);
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xff0000
    })
  );
  scene.add(mesh);
  camera.position.z = 5;
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(width, height);

  function destroy() {
    console.log("destroy");
    scene = null;
    camera = null;
    mesh = null;
    renderer.dispose();
  }

  function animate() {
    if (!renderer) return;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  animate();
  return { destroy, domElement: renderer.domElement };
}

let iframe;
const getIframe = () => {
  const code = generateCodeFromProjectData();
  const root = document.getElementById("root");
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.setAttribute("id", "testing_frame");
  iframe.setAttribute("class", "ui");
  iframe.style.width = "300px";
  iframe.style.height = "300px";
  root.appendChild(iframe);
  const iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
  iframeDoc.open();
  iframeDoc.write(code);
  iframeDoc.close();
  const body = iframeDoc.querySelector("body");
  const instance = init(body.clientWidth, body.clientHeight);
  body.appendChild(instance.domElement);
  function destroy() {
    root.removeChild(iframe);
    instance.destroy();
  }
  return { iframe, iframeDoc, destroy };
};

function test_iframe() {
  if (!iframe) {
    // init
    console.log("init");
    iframe = getIframe();
    document.getElementById("play_btn").innerHTML = "Stop";
    return;
  }
  console.log("dispose");
  // disposing
  document.getElementById("play_btn").innerHTML = "Play";
  iframe.destroy();
  iframe = null;
}

function generateCodeFromProjectData() {
  generatedCode = "";
  //Opening
  generatedCode += `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body style="margin: 0;width: 300px;height:300px;">
    </body>
    </html>`;

  return generatedCode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now there is no more `Context Lost` errors, but the red cube in the center isn't showing up? I've edited my answer showing my full code for the `iframe`

Comment: @Anye I have added a working demo and also provided a solution for multiple instances being imported hope you like it. 